# Phonegap Build and Recaptcha don't work together

Tags: phonegap-build, recaptcha

I'm doing an app using Phonegap Build and I don't want to be spammed so I have integrated Recaptcha. It works properly in web browsers but it doesn't in the native app created by Phonegap Build. A error message is given by recaptcha in the plugin instead of  the checkbox.

The message is "Invalid domain for site key".

The few results I found on the Web are about copying and pasting the JS file of recaptcha into my js folder, in short, make it mine. And as it's written on this file, it's not allowed by Google.

Do you know other ways to solve this problem ?